# How can I count the number of times each word appears in a txt file?

Tags: python

Here is the assignment in detail:
Write a complete python program which reads words from a file called trash.dat.  Assume there is one word per line in the file.  Output the count for each of the different words (case insensitive) in the file.  For example a file with:

```py
dog

Dog

cat

rat
```

Would output:

```py
dog=2

cat=1

rat=1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, SO is not a code writing service, you need to show your efforts

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Note that it's OK to ask about homework, but you need to show some effort as well. What have you tried already? What isn't working? See this post for a detailed explanation on how to ask and answer homework questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok so what have you tried that didn't work ? Where's your code ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: here's a python program that does what you want: `print('\n'.join(map('%s=%d'.__mod__, Counter(map(str.lower, map(str.strip, open('trash.dat')))).items())))`

Answer (score 1):

You should go off and do your own homework to help you learn. But regardless, here is a solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

dict = {}

with open("trash.dat", "rw") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line != "\n":
            if line.lower() in dict:
                dict[line.lower()] = dict[line.lower()] + 1
            else:
                dict[line.lower()] = 1

for x in dict:
    print "%s=" % x, dict[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!python2

from collections import Counter

words = []

# load words to list
with open('trash.dat', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line != '\n':
            words.append(line.lower().rstrip())

# make a dictionary from the 'words' list
cnt = Counter(words)

# print out the key, value pairs
for k, v in cnt.items():
    print 'the count of ' + k + ' is: ' + str(v)

'''
# output
the count of rat is: 1
the count of dog is: 2
the count of cat is: 1
''''
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
theWords = []
with open('fileName.dat', 'r') as file:
for every line in file:
    theWords.append(line.lower().rstrip("\n"))

print("Rat = " + theWords[1])
print("Dog = " + theWords[2])
print("Cat = " + theWords[3])
```

Every line in your file will be seperated.